# Using arrow write_dataset function to append parquet data

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

We are using arrow dataset write_dataset functionin pyarrow to write arrow data to a base_dir - "/tmp" in a parquet format. When the base_dir is empty part-0.parquet file is created. however when trying to write again new data to the base_dir part-0.parquet is overwritten. I would expect to see part-1.parquet with the new data in base_dir. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you can use is a combination of parameters `basename_template` and `existing_data_behavior` of the `ds.write_dataset()` to generate random or specific pattern to rename partition filenames. For example:

```py
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> import pyarrow.dataset as ds
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2020, 2022, 2021],
...                    'b': [3, 5, 7]})
>>> table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
>>> 
>>> for k in range(3):
...     ds.write_dataset(table, base_dir="dataset", format="parquet",
...                      partitioning=['a'],
...                      basename_template="part-{{i}}-{}.parquet".format(k),
...                      existing_data_behavior='overwrite_or_ignore' # you could also use 'delete_matching'
...                     )
...     print(k)
...     ds.dataset("dataset", format="parquet").files
... 
0
['dataset/2020/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2021/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2022/part-0-0.parquet']
1
['dataset/2020/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2020/part-0-1.parquet', 'dataset/2021/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2021/part-0-1.parquet', 'dataset/2022/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2022/part-0-1.parquet']
2
['dataset/2020/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2020/part-0-1.parquet', 'dataset/2020/part-0-2.parquet', 'dataset/2021/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2021/part-0-1.parquet', 'dataset/2021/part-0-2.parquet', 'dataset/2022/part-0-0.parquet', 'dataset/2022/part-0-1.parquet', 'dataset/2022/part-0-2.parquet']
>>>
```

See also:

- https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#writing-datasets
- [How to control whether pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset will overwrite previous data or append to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071323/how-to-control-whether-pyarrow-dataset-write-dataset-will-overwrite-previous-dat)

Comment: I was looking in a scenario where I want to add new lines to an existing table written in parquet by writing a new parquet file to the base_dir. can you please explain how partitioning is used to append the new data? Thanks

Comment: `partition_filename_cb` is probably a little bit of a misnomer as it isn't very related to partitioning.  In the newer `write_dataset` API, which it sounds like you might be using, the field has been renamed to `basename_template` to reflect this fact.  However, using a unique template for each write call is indeed the way to avoid overwriting old files.

Comment: Sorry, I misread which API you are using. Edited the answer to reflect the use of the `write_dataset` API and its parameters.